# Cannot find symbol class in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have two project A and B where B is added as a module of project A. I have added dependencies in A's Gradle build file. Now i can import B's class in A without any error (in editor) but can't build. Preferences is a class of project B.

## Error

```
Error:(22, 23) error: cannot find symbol class Preferences
```

## A's build file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.A"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile project(':B')
}
```

## B's build file

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

apply plugin: "android-library"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 11
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
        }
    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jniLibs'
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }

    task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
        if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
            commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
        } else {
            commandLine '/opt/adt-bundle-linux/android-ndk-r8e/ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
        }
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
}
```

I can successfully build the project(A) if remove the import.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have pointed out the problem. `TargetSdk version` and `support package version` of two project are not same. After changing these with latest version, my problem is solved.

Answer (score 44):

It can happen if the library (be it a local module or external dependency) has a `minifyEnabled true`, but library's ProGuard configuration is missing or not correct (the class is eligible for removing by ProGuard). This leads to class not being compiled.

Comment: how can we minify our library in this case?

Comment: Generally speaking the decision if the library's classes must be minified should be left to the consumer of the library. But if you need to force minify of your library you can just set `minifyEnabled true` but you must be sure your ProGuard configuration does not remove something important. I'm not quite sure if that can be guaranteed. ProGuard has always been a source of "last-minute-before-release" headaches.

Answer (score 10):

For me it was a similar problem but on proguard conf. proguard was active on a first library and inactive on a second.

Copie same proguard conf on all build.gradle has solved the "cannot find symbol class" error.

Comment: My problem was related - under buildTypes, "minifyEnabled" was set to "true" in one module and "false" in the app module. I set it to false in both, and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error come up when I added a new module to my project.

To fix it, I also had to change
`minSdkVersion`,
`targetSdkVersion`,
`buildToolsVersion`, and
`compileSdkVersion` to match the `build.gradle` in my original module.

After I did these things the error was still coming up so I set `minifyEnabled` to `false` and then it compiled and ran!

Comment: You can either set `minifyEnabled` to `false` to get it to run or keep `minifyEnabled` set to `true` and correct the proguard rules in your proguard configuration file.

Comment: @Fra - the rules differ per app and requires an understanding of Proguard rules syntax. There's no one set of rules that works for all apps.

Comment: @Adil - I know i'm finding out the hard way. The problem lies in the code obfuscation for me. Are you aware of how to keep a public interface name using -keep command? I am able to keep the method names in the class but not the interface.

Comment: @Fra - you might find this Blog post of mine helpful: https://adilatwork.blogspot.co.uk/2015/12/proguard-rules-for-building-library.html

Comment: @Adil - Thanks. To clarify then, if I have a class com.company.other.myclass would I need to write -keep public interface com.company.other.myclass.** {
    <methods>;
}

Comment: @Fra - No. If your interface is `com.company.other.myclass` then the rule you want is `-keep public interface com.company.other.myclass { <methods>; }`. But please take some time to understand the syntax of Proguard rules before writing your own Proguard rules because it can be very confusing if you're not familiar with the syntax and how the rules work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I have implemented a library B via a local maven repository in my app project A. But some classes from B could not be resolved when building A, wheareas others were working fine. In my case i had to **invalidate caches/restart** B,  in addition to that also **delete the module build folder** in B, recompile B, and sync A. This was again some wierd bug in AndroidStudio which took me hours solving.